# Is gravity a centripetal force?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, centripetal-force

In curved space-time, there are curved paths. Since curved paths in our experience require some centripetal force to create them, isn't then gravity a centripetal force?

Comment: In general relativity we are treating gravity as a fictitious force i.e. a force term that is caused by the description of nature in a non-inertial system. The underlying experimental observation is the equivalence principle, which allows us to define local inertial systems (that of free falling test particles), in which the force of gravity is alway zero. Is this what you meant in your question?

Comment: We all were schooled that there are 4 forces in physics:
strong nuclear force,
weak nuclear force,
electromagnetic force,
gravitational force.

Well under which of the above would centripetal force fit?
What complicates this further is when we are told under general relativity that gravity is not really a force, but rather the tendency for masses to go where time passes more slowly which is what happens when space-time is curved by a very large mass.

Answer (score 2):

The strong analogy is between gravity and fictitious forces. Of course centripetal force is the special case of rotating reference frames.

In Newtonian Physics you have $F=ma$, that is valid in an inertial frame. Suppose that we want to describe a particle that is moving with constant velocity, so $a=0$. If you want to study the same system in a non-inertial frame, than you need to add some fictitious forces: $$F=ma=0 \rightarrow F+F_{app}=ma=0$$

In general relativity, if the space is flat (no gravity) a particle moves on a straight line in space-time and follow a geodesic given by $\frac{d^2 \xi^{\mu}}{d \tau^2}=0$. If the space is curved, than the particle has, in general,  a curved geodesic, given by: 
$$\frac{d^2 \xi^{\mu}}{d \tau^2}=0 \rightarrow \frac{d^2 x^{\mu}}{d \tau^2}+\Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu \rho}\frac{d x^{\nu}}{d \tau}\frac{d x^{\rho}}{d \tau}=0$$

Comment: I think you have answered the question "Is gravity a *centrifugal* force?" (correctly, I might add).

Comment: I've not paid attention to minus signs, if this is what you mean!

Answer (score 1):

Insofar as the gravitational force points towards the 'centre of gravity' of an object (like the earth or the sun), it can be considered a 'centre seeking' or *centripetal* force.